# Unity 64-bit build failing according to Play Store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to upload a new update for my Android App but Goolge Play Console always gives this error:

> This release does not comply to the 64-bits requirements of Google
>   Play
>
> The following APK's or app-bundles are available for 64-bits devices,
>   but only have 32-bits native code: *BUNDLE_ID*.

(freely translated from Dutch, and With *BUNDLE_ID* a real bundle id)

This is my build configuration

[image: Build configuration]

And I've got a custom gradle file because I had to add

> abifilters

for an external library. Here is my MainTemplate.gradle

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
**BUILD_SCRIPT_DEPS**}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

// Android Resolver Repos Start
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        def unityProjectPath = "file:///" + file(rootProject.projectDir.path + "/../../").absolutePath
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url (unityProjectPath + "/Assets/Firebase/m2repository") // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:20, Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:20
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com/" // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7
        }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// Android Resolver Repos End
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:15
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-unity:6.2.2' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:20
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:6.2.2' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:20
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:18.0.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[19.0.1]' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:15
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
**DEPS**}

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        applicationId '**APPLICATIONID**'
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'**STREAMING_ASSETS**]
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }**SIGN**

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_DEBUG**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_DEBUG**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD****SIGNCONFIG**
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_RELEASE**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_RELEASE**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD****SIGNCONFIG**
        }
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS****SPLITS**
**BUILT_APK_LOCATION**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}**SPLITS_VERSION_CODE****REPOSITORIES****SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
```

My Unity version is 2019.2.0f1 but the same problem was present in 2019.1.9f1

Comment: If you are using abifilters you are telling your build process to only build for those architectures. Since there are no 64-bit ones in your filter you are stripping out the 64bit files you need.

Comment: So if I were to remove them (or add 64 bit), it should be ok? But I added them in the first place because of an external plugin that an .so file for only armeabi-v7a and x86. If I remove the abifilters line then this plugin wont get loaded

Comment: It should be okay. You'll either need to figure out how to get your external library working on 64 bit or do a 32bit only build

Answer (score 0):

this line is not include 64-bit :

```
abiFilters "armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
```

it should be:

```
abiFilters "armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
```